# What is the command line used by CLion when invoking CMake?

Tags: build, cmake, clion

What is exactly the command line (process and arguments) used by CLion  when invoking CMake? I'm trying to use the same directory for manual builds using the terminal and for building using the IDE, but it seems that one is interacting badly with the other.

I have no problem with using CLion only to handle CMake configurations (to avoid slight configuration mismatch triggering another CMake execution), but it seems that even standard builds using `make` on the command line trigger `cmake` again.

I've seen that CLion prints it's "call" to CMake, but I don't see where it references the current working directory. And since on the GUI you configure paths relative to the project root folder (where `CMakeLists.txt` live), instead of relative to the build folder. I was hoping that this detail is the culprit here.

Usually in the command line I'd do it like this:

```
$ cd project
$ mkdir -p builds/debug
$ cd builds/debug
$ cmake $MY_CMAKE_OPTS -DSPECIAL_FILE=../../file.ext ../..
```

On CLion, though, I have to configure it like this:

```
CMake options: $MY_CMAKE_OPTS -DSPECIAL_FILE=file.ext
Generation path: builds/debug
The rest I've used the default
```

This *special file* is used on the configuration phase, so using paths other than relative to project root or absolute paths won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Configuration step** command line is shown in CMake view when you load/reload a CMake project: `View - Tool Windows - CMake`. The view has no default hotkey.

Example: `/Users/vic/bin/cmake_ninja_wrapper.py -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/user/src/helloworld`.

Depending on configuration, the current directory can be `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR/cmake-build-debug` (where the build files were generated for me), `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR/cmake-build-release`, or other.

**Build step** command line is shown in `Messages - Build` view. It opens when you invoke build from Build menu. I don't think the current directory matters for it, as all the build files are already generated.

Example: `/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/user/src/helloworld/cmake-build-debug --target helloworld -- -j 6`

Then the view can be opened with `Cmd-0` on Mac, or through menu: `View - 
Tool Windows - Messages`.

To work with relative paths, you can refer to [PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) variable in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: I've seen it, but I can't figure out where this is run, what is the directory it's called in. Maybe it's omitting just the source and build folder parameters?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the essential part - configuration step. Updated the answer.